# Responsive First Column in a Responsive Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, whitespace

The first column of six columns table filled with various length of content. I want to make it responsive with only one row, cutted by overflow hidden and ellipsis, while maintain the table still responsive in mobile viewport with 100% width.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;    
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td {
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam that is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above makes the table become not responsive and failed to resize the first column as expected.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8jke605/)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to solve this problem.

The secret is to make 2 different position within the TD that contain ellipsis text. This can be done by adding a new span element within the TD with **position:absolute**, while the TD itself use **position:relative**.

STEPS:

1. Style all TD with **white-space:nowrap;**
2. Style first TD  with **width:100%** and **position:relative**
3. Style the span element within the TD with **position:absolute;**  **overflow: hidden;**    **text-overflow: ellipsis;**  **left: 0;**    **right: 0;**

Complete code on my working solution:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif; */
}
table {
 max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;  
 display: table;
 table-layout: auto; 
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
td:nth-child(1):not(:empty)::after {
  /* Prevent row from collapsing vertically if the first column is empty */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
td:nth-child(1) > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><span>overflow-x:auto around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed</span></td>      <td><span>Smith</span></td>      <td><span>50</span></td>      <td><span>50</span></td>      <td><span>50</span></td>      <td><span>50</span></td>      <td><span>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><span>Eve Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table</span></td>      <td><span>Mike</span></td>      <td><span><span>94</span></span></td>      <td><span><span>94</span></span></td>      <td><span><span>94</span></span></td>      <td><span><span>94</span></span></td>      <td><span><span>94</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><span>Adamthat is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table</span></td>      <td><span>Johnson</span></td>      <td><span>67</span></td>      <td><span>67</span></td>      <td><span>67</span></td>      <td><span>67</span></td>      <td><span>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret lies in `display: block`; ellipsis only applies to block-level elements. As such, you'll want to add the following rules to the relevant `<td>` elements:

```
display: block;
width: 100px; /* However wide you want the cell to be before ellipsis */
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This should only be applied to the first `<td>` element in each row, so you can use the selector `td:first-of-type`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

td:first-of-type {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ellipsis">around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam that is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that you'll want to use pixel-based units rather than percentages, as with percentage the ellipsis will take effect, but the cell itself will still occupy `100%` of the width.

Comment: If I set fixed width for first td, the td will become not responsive in wider viewport. My expectation is the first td can follow the screen width as well.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the style class below to your table cell individually should make the texts clip.

```
<style>
 .clipText{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
 }
 .clipText:hover{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
 }
</style>
```

and i would suggest if your trying to make a responsive table use css media query and display the table elements as blocks for small screens and arrange them as you see fit and a little js dom manipulation can also make it better using screen size as a condition.

```
      <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px){
            table, th, tr, td{
                display: block;
            }
            table tr:first-child{
                display: none;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even){
                background-color: royalblue;
                position: relative;
                margin: 2% 0%;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd){
                background-color: grey;
                position: relative;
                margin: 2% 0%;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) td{
                color: white;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
                color: black;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }
            table td:nth-child(1)::before{
                content: "Content: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(2)::before{
                content: "Name: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(3)::before{
                content: "Points: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(4)::before{
                content: "Points: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(5)::before{
                content: "Points: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(6)::before{
                content: "Points: ";
            }
            table td:nth-child(7)::before{
                content: "Points: ";
            }
        }
    </style>
```

to see the effects of the style above reduce/ minimize your browser size/width.

Comment: @DrunkenM both codes are working fine for the first you have to add it as a class to the td element you want the effect on `<td class="clipText">i am a content<td>` and for the second all you have to do is reduce the size of the browser or view screen

Comment: @DrunkenM by reducing the size i mean try dragging your browser window form left to right as if to make it smaller, even works in the js fiddle drag the small screen where the table is shown on the bottom left corner from left to right that's how `media queries` work :) it's triggered by screen size